App Engine server-server OAuth2 request blocked by Context-aware access location policy
We have an application that integrates with Google Drive API to allow the user to access their files directly from our application. The Frontend for this application is accessed via an AWS Cloudfront pointing to S3, with the backend identity services running in App engine.
The customer is able to authenticate with their google account in the frontend application with CAA policy as this call is being made from the Client device and their IP is being passed in the request, however when the user attempts to enable drive integration, the OAuth2 request is being made from our backend service which now fails because the OAuth2 request is being made server to server not client to server, and thus the IP google workspace sees is the Private IPv6 of the backend server.
Ideally we would like to not whitelist the App in CAA policies as we do not want the app to be a backdoor to avoid workspace restrictions and just want to grant the same access as the Client already has.
We have tried the follow:

adding the VPC Cloud NAT IP addresses to the CAA policy as an or statement.
Adding Googles known services IP address to the CAA policy
Blocking all IPv6 egress traffic to get the IPv4 IP of the restricted request
Setup the VPC to be IPv4 single stack

Regardless of what changes we currently have made the logs in the Google workspace always show a private IPv6 address if the OAuth2 request is coming from our backend service and not direct from client device.
